# PyQt - Open the same page several times

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want, from my Index.py page, to open several times the page Form.py.
For the moment when i try to open Form a second time the first Form page closes.

There is my Index.py code :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Form import Ui_FormWindow

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    #The function to open the Form.py
    def open(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_FormWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 180, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the page i want to open several times, Form.py :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_FormWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, FormWindow):
        FormWindow.setObjectName("FormWindow")
        FormWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(FormWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 190, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        FormWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(FormWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        FormWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(FormWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        FormWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(FormWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FormWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, FormWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        FormWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("FormWindow", "FormWindow"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("FormWindow", "Page to open"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    FormWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_FormWindow()
    ui.setupUi(FormWindow)
    FormWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419530/pyqt4-generating-multiple-instances-of-the-same-widget) but i don't understand how to make it work in my code.
I also edited my question in order to be a minimal reproducible example but my english is not perfect and i fear to not understand perfectly what i read on the mre tutotial so sorry

Comment: provide a [mRE]

Comment: @eyllanesc i add more code, i don't see what to give more

Comment: Have you read that it is an MRE ?, your code is not so if you want help provide it, when you do let me know

Comment: @eyllanesc done but my english is not very great and i don't know if i understand perfectly what it is so sorry if it's not what you want

Comment: 1) add `self.ws = []` in `setupUi()` of Index.py 2) change to `def open(self):
 w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_FormWindow()
    ui.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    self.ws.append(w)
    self.window.show()`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done QT stuff in a while but could it be the fact that you're instancing `QtWidgets.QMainWindow` again? That'd be my first guess.